# AppCompatButton does not show on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-studio

I put two android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton in a linear layout. They show and work fine in Android versions 4.x and 5.x, but do not show up on Version 6 (The phone is S7 Edge).

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAsk"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_ask"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_buy"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I googled it and checked SOF for a possible solution but could not find anything working.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This surely is an interesting phenomenon. Why do you need to use `AppCompatButton` anyway? What does regular button fail to achieve?

Comment: @Vucko: This library includes support for material design user interface implementations. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don`t know exactly how that happened but I changed the layout from

`LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`

and the buttons showed up. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Button` in your layout instead of specifying `AppCompatButton` as according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html) for `AppCompatButton`:

> [AppCompatButton] will automatically be used when you use Button in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

Comment: I will try that and give feedback asap. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @erolyeniaras Any luck?

Comment: I changed it to Button but did not solve it. Then I switched back to AppCompatButton and changed the layout from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and buttons showed up. Puzzled. I have reported it to Google.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that the Orientation property from the LinearLayout was not set, the default is horizontal which causes the views not to show specially if there's a first view with MATCH_PARENT width.